# Concatenating Rows or columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, string, concatenation, paste

Working with R:

I took multiple strings of letters:

```
Orig1 - ABCDE

Orig2 - FGHIJ

Orig3 - KLMNO
```

I split those strings of letters using `strsplit`:

```
Orig1 - A B C D E

Orig2 - F G H I J

Orig3 - K L M N O
```

And I put each letter in its own row and column in a dataframe. Each string on its own row with each subsequent letter in its own column:

```
RowName   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5

Orig1     A  B  C  D  E

Orig2     F  G  H  I  J

Orig3     K  L  M  N  O
```

I manipulated these strings of letters to come up with a multiple altered strings based on various analyses of these strings of letters:

```
RowName   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5

Altered1  A  G  H  N  E

Altered2  F  B  C  I  O

Altered3  K  L  M  D  J
```

I can't figure out how to collapse the altered strings back out of the dataframe.  I need this to be able to be converted into an exportable .fasta file with the rownames as the subsequent sequence names.

Paste didn't work within the dataframe, so I tried using a bit of code from another thread on a similar subject:

```
ldf = lapply(as.list(1:dim(df)[1]), function(x) df[x[1],])
```

this put each into its own list, which I could then use paste on, but I found the output baffling to try to export.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want this

```
> do.call(paste,c(df[-1],sep = ""))
[1] "AGHNE" "FBCIO" "KLMDJ"
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(RowName = c("Altered1", "Altered2", "Altered3"
), V1 = c("A", "F", "K"), V2 = c("G", "B", "L"), V3 = c("H", 
"C", "M"), V4 = c("N", "I", "D"), V5 = c("E", "O", "J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

> df
   RowName V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 Altered1  A  G  H  N  E
2 Altered2  F  B  C  I  O
3 Altered3  K  L  M  D  J
```

Comment: Thank you.  This gave me a list that I could work with.  I've never quite got a handle on do.call.  It seems to be a catch-all that can solve a lot of problems though.  I'll have to read up on it more.

Answer (score 0):

If we want the rowwise `paste`oing

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
reduce(select(df, -1), str_c, sep="")
#[1] "AGHNE" "FBCIO" "KLMDJ"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(RowName = c("Altered1", "Altered2", "Altered3"
), V1 = c("A", "F", "K"), V2 = c("G", "B", "L"), V3 = c("H", 
"C", "M"), V4 = c("N", "I", "D"), V5 = c("E", "O", "J")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I couldn't get the select command to work out of dplyr for some reason.  R is all up to date and everything.  Idk.  Still wanted to thank you for your reply.

Comment: @IanHauffe `select` is one function that can be from different packages.  I used the `select` from `dplyr`.  If you had loaded other packages, it could be masked.  So, you specify `purrr::reduce(dplyr::select(df, -1), str_c, sep="")`